# Is it possible to have local CS : GO ranking?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Being college students we usually play on college lan. Is it somehow possible that we have a local ranking system for just the players connecting to our local servers?

Comment: This is most likely not possible on a software level without setting up a system like faceit or esea to track ranks, since the CSGO client doesn't natively support leagues. But i would like to see where this goes!

Comment: I would suggest setting up a dedicated server and use a plug in to track ranks. I'm pretty sure there's a plug in out there that does this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run an ***external*** local ranking system, you should give a try to [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system for sports, games, and more.

It's free to use and it's designed to manage rankings for small or large groups of players. 
We've got many group using it for *Smash Bros*, *League of Legends*, *Dota*, *Fifa*, *CSGO*, and more. Rankade can manage any kind of match: one-on-one, faction vs. faction (two teams, which may be asymmetrical), multiplayer, multi-faction, cooperative games, single player games, and so on.

Rankade doesn't use **Elo**, as CSGO ranking do, but its algorithm (called *ree* algorithm), although more complex, is similar to Elo. Here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison), and here's the link for our [dojo](https://rankade.com/dojo), where you'll find links to some of our featured public groups.

Comment: As a note: CS:GO ranking system doesn't use ELO either. It uses a custom rating algorithm based on Glicko 2.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I wrote *Elo* just because usually people refers to *CSGO Elo*. As you know, Glicko is Elo's '*son*', and CSGO ranking system is not *pure* Glicko, indeed. In the comparison I linked, both Elo and Glicko (and TrueSkill too) are considered.

Comment: The above answer seems to involve a lot of manual work, which is fine by all means. I was looking for something that would install on our local game server and keep records of the matches played on that game server.

Comment: After group setup, it's about 10 seconds for each match insertion (additional infos are prefilled from previous match, you just need to select factions' members). It's not *a lot of manual work* at all, :) but it's not automated (it's 'external', as I wrote), so it doesn't fit your needs as per your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively... However, if you install a dedicated server, you can install [MetaMod](https://www.metamodsource.net/) and [SourceMod](https://www.sourcemod.net/). And then you can install the [Simple CSGO Ranks](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=2306795) plugin or a similar alternative.

This should do the trick, and let you and your friends have your own local rank system. Of course, you'll need to play on the same dedicated server instance from that point on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This could be exactly what I was looking for. Will see how it works out.

Comment: @abhilash-singh did it work out as expected?

Answer (score 1):

The Simple CSGO Ranks sourcemod plugin was developed for people who don't want to go through the hassle of either paying for a ranking system like GameMe or using the ingame MM ranking system. It has a focus on storing information which can be used to generate player statistics along with ranking.

By Default:
Everytime a player gets a kill their rank increases by 5.
When a player is killed their rank decreases by 6.
When a player assists a kill their rank increases by 2.
When a player is much lower rank than the player they killed the numbers are 10 and 11.
When a player defuses the bomb their rank increases by 5.

It also has modes for deathmatch and free for all game modes.

For those who also want to get involved or have up to the minute versions the [GitHub](https://github.com/ArclightHub/Simple-CSGO-Ranks/) repo is here.

It should contain all of the information required to help you set it up on your own server! It should be as easy as setting up Sourcemod, MySQL and putting the plugin into the plugins folder ;)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Arqade!  This doesn't explain how it answers the question.  Could you explain what the Simple CSGO Ranks plugin actually does so that people can tell if it fits their use case?